# Help repairing broken Python base on Linux with Miniedit-WiFi setup

Tags: command-line, wireless, dependencies, python3, paths

> I previously uninstalled Python3.12 (on which I had ran Miniedit-WiFi
> tool) and left the default Python3.11; however the following
> console-log error keeps popping out whenever I run a Python script on the
> Python3.11 regardless of whether I run from a Virtual environment or
> from the base Python interpreter. (The
> default Python3.11 is also however still broken too as I cannot
> install anymore packages using pip despite other projects than the. (This is on `Kubuntu-Mantic`)

> I have ran another TensorFlow ML script that works well in its virtual
> environment and realized that the issue is in the Python sudoer
> system; the console output I shared above always comes when I try run
> a Python script with sudo privilege (eg: `sudo python3 /path/to/any/python/script` ); So I opened all the setup files in
> `/etc/sudoers.d/` but could not see any trace of the Python3.12 path
> setup yet the Python path is clean with only the default base
> Python3.11 & Python3.7  This issue can after I used the `sudome` app
> for automating `sudo` privilege for my Miniedit project in Pycharm
> when I had Python3.12 install, but after I uninstalled the Python3.12
> and cleared it out of the Python path, I can no longer run Python
> scripts with `sudo` privilege as the console output suggests its
> Python path pointing to the Python3.12 which I uninstalled already.
> Can anyone can help me trace where this output is coming from

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/usr/local/lib/python3.12'
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python312.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f5dbb036740 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Comment: You've not yet told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using; ie. details of what *software stack* you're using.  On anything `python3` related, that detail is helpful (*python3 is a system tool, esp. on desktop systems*)

Comment: Let me update with those specifications/information; but for now, I have retried running another TensorFlow ML script that works well in its virtual environment and realized that the issue is in the Python sudoer system; the console output I shared above always comes when I try run a Python script with sudo privilege (eg: `sudo python3 /path/to/any/python/script` ); So I opened all the setup files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` but could not see any trace of the Python3.12 path setup yet the Python path is clean with only the default base Python3.11 & Python3.7 (Kubuntu-Mantic)

Answer (score 0):

I realized the base Python3.11 configuration file and base-script were in `/usr/local/bin/` so I used in the terminal:

`sudo nano /usr/local/bin/python3-config`

to edit every instance of `3.12` to `3.11`, saved the config file and finally

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

Rebooted the PC and it worked!